# what to create a animated line threw text that is in a link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating my website for job and in my navigation bar i have 3 links.
1. about
2.projects
3.contact.

these text are all in an (a) tag.
and the a tag is wraped in a div container.
On hover(of the links), I want an animated white line to pass threw(middle) of the text. ONLY ON HOVER.

css/javascript/jquery solutions only please.

Comment: Where's the markup? What have you tried so far?

Comment: the markup is a div and 3 a tags in them and thats it. I have idea how to even start it.(Atleast with pure js or jquery).

Comment: You don't need JS. This is all achievable with CSS but you would need a basic understanding of HTML/CSS. So post the markup you have and maybe somebody will show you how.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `:before` pseudo element to create the element and simply animate its width on hover.

E.G: This or something like it.

```css
div {
  display:inline-block; padding:10px; margin:0 10px 10px 0;
  background:#333333;
}
div > a {
  position: relative;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
div > a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
div > a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 50%;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
} 
div > a:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
<a href="#">About</a>
</div><div>
<a href="#">Projects</a>
</div><div>
<a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks to you, My website can move forward. Thank you my friend, this tell me that i have to now go and study pseudo classes. thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS.
Unfortunately the `text-decoration` property is not animatable.

```
a:hover{
      text-decoration:line-through;
    }
```

**EDIT:** I see there is a better solution above, I suggest you use that as opposed to the built-in strikethrough value.

Comment: thats the problem. I need it to be animated

Answer (score 0):

here's a [pen](https://codepen.io/scottmurphy1111/pen/Yrpaba)

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="">link1</a>
    <span class="line-pass-through">
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="">link2</a>
    <span class="line-pass-through">      
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="">link3</a>
    <span class="line-pass-through">      
  </li>
</ul>
```

css

```
li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 25px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: cornflowerblue;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.line-pass-through {
  position: absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:1px;
  background: #444;
  transform: translate(-100%, 50%);
  top: 50%;
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
}

li:hover .line-pass-through {
  transform: translate(0%, 50%);
}
```