# Animated CSS strikethrough text decoration over links

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I'm referring to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78088612/14512582). What if there is a link within the `span` needed to be strikethrough, too? How to get the red line in front of the entire text including the link, while the link still remains clickable?

```css
span {
  background: 
    linear-gradient(red 0 0) no-repeat 
    0 60% / var(--s,0%) .1em,
    #000;
  -webkit-background-clip: border-box, text;
          background-clip: border-box, text;
  color: #0000;
  transition: background-size .4s ease;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

span:hover {
  --s: 100%;
}

span a {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<span>
  <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</a> At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
</span>
```

Comment: In your example link is still clickable.... so i don't understand what do you want to achieve.

Comment: @Sfili_81 The red line is not in front of the link but behind it.

Comment: You're applying the strikethrough on the background; of course it's going to be behind the content. You need to move the link text behind the background if you want the background to appear in front of it. But then the link is not going to be clickable.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46393858/what-to-create-a-animated-line-threw-text-that-is-in-a-link

Comment: @TylerH The special thing about the answer to which I refer in my question is that the red line is brought in front of the text using `background-clip`. The red line is above the unlinked text as desired, just not above the linked text, that's the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem here is that there is a transparent box on top of the link, causing the link to not work. I tried to fix, but I couldent.

Ok, so I made the line go in front of the link, but I couldn't figure how to make the link work. Maybe you shouldn't use the  tag and just code a link with JavaScript like if you click the text it will do `window.open("google.com")` and style it to make it like a link.

```css
span {
  background: linear-gradient(red 0 0) no-repeat 0 60% / var(--s, 0%) .1em, #000;
  -webkit-background-clip: border-box, text;
  background-clip: border-box, text;
  color: #0000;
  transition: background-size .4s ease;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  position: relative;
}

span:hover {
  --s: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

span a {
  color: green;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<span>
  <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</a> At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
</span>
```

Comment: You've moved the strikethrough in front of the link, but now the link is not clickable due to that fact. So, you've traded one problem for another.

Comment: Yeah lol, i have no idea how to fix it